# How to create a custom method for `by` operator in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have spots dialog in several fragments.

```
private val spotsDialog: SpotsDialog by lazy {
        SpotsDialog(requireContext(), getString(R.string.loading), R.style.SpotsDialogTheme)
    }
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a custom method for the **by** operator, something like this?

```
private val spotsDialog: SpotsDialog by spotsDialogs()
```

Comment: Should be possible, so long as `spotsDialog()` returns an object that has the appropriate `operator` function(s). For instance, `lazy` returns an instance of [`Lazy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-lazy/). See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html

Comment: I believe you may be looking for info on `Delegates` ?
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, to create dialog I need context.

If we declare spotsDialog like a global variable we don't have access to context on fragment initialization, but we can pass the fragment like parameter and then get context from fragment.

```
// In fragment
private val spotsDialog: SpotsDialog by SpotsDialogs()
```

```
class SpotsDialogs {

    private var spotsDialog: SpotsDialog? = null

    operator fun getValue(fragment: Fragment, property: KProperty<*>): SpotsDialog {
        if (spotsDialog == null) {
            spotsDialog = SpotsDialog(
                    fragment.requireContext(),
                    fragment.requireContext().getString(R.string.loading),
                    R.style.SpotsDialogTheme
            )
        }
        return spotsDialog!!
    }
}
```

Comment: `return spotsDialog!!` is bad practice, try to avoid it. In this case:  `private lateinit var spotsDialog: SpotsDialog` is better.